# How to be sure that I stopped locationManager requestUpdates?

Tags: android, android-location

I am looking for the location of my current position but only once, I cannot use requestSingleUpdate because it needs to run on Android versions lower than 2.3. I call this through TimerTask and when I get the position, I stop timer.cancel().  How to be sure that I stopped locationManager requestUpdates? ( I called locationManager.removeUpdates but is there any another way to monitor requests )

Answer (score 3):

if you call timer.cancel the locationupdatelistener continue working. you only can use locationManager.removeUpdates, this is 100%secure that stop updating